# Consumir objeto con caracteres especiales

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy haciendo una petición a una API pero regresa un objeto con caracteres especiales por lo que no puedo imprimirla.

mi código es:

```
function estatus(Emisor, Receptor, Total, Uuid) {
    axios.get(`API`)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
```

El resultado de response.data es:

```
{
"s:Envelope": {
    "_attributes": {
        "xmlns:s": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    },
    "s:Body": {
        "ConsultaResponse": {
            "_attributes": {
                "xmlns": "http://tempuri.org/"
            },
            "ConsultaResult": {
                "_attributes": {
                    "xmlns:a": "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sat.Cfdi.Negocio.ConsultaCfdi.Servicio",
                    "xmlns:i": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                },
                "a:CodigoEstatus": {
                    "_text": "S - Comprobante obtenido satisfactoriamente."
                },
                "a:EsCancelable": {
                    "_text": "No cancelable"
                },
                "a:Estado": {
                    "_text": "Vigente"
                },
                "a:EstatusCancelacion": {},
                "a:ValidacionEFOS": {
                    "_text": "200"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Necesito imprimir el Estado pero cuando intento con un response.data.s:Envelope marca error y no me deja continuar.

Comment: Solo necesitas acceder con notación de corchetes: `console.log(response.data['s:Envelope']);`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, intento llegar al "a:Estado" pero sigo sin lograrlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando las propiedades contienen caracteres especiales, solo necesitas acceder con notación de corchetes, encerrando entre comillas la propiedad. Incluso, puedes combinar las dos formas.

Sigue el camino hasta llegar a la propiedad deseada:

```
-> data
  -> 's:Envelope'          // Corchetes y comillas obligatorios
    -> 's:Body'            // Corchetes y comillas obligatorios
      -> ConsultaResponse  // Corchetes o .nombreDePropiedad
        -> ConsultaResult  // Corchetes o .nombreDePropiedad
          -> 'a:Estado'    // Corchetes y comillas obligatorios
```

```js
let data = {
"s:Envelope": {
    "_attributes": {
        "xmlns:s": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    },
    "s:Body": {
        "ConsultaResponse": {
            "_attributes": {
                "xmlns": "http://tempuri.org/"
            },
            "ConsultaResult": {
                "_attributes": {
                    "xmlns:a": "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Sat.Cfdi.Negocio.ConsultaCfdi.Servicio",
                    "xmlns:i": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                },
                "a:CodigoEstatus": {
                    "_text": "S - Comprobante obtenido satisfactoriamente."
                },
                "a:EsCancelable": {
                    "_text": "No cancelable"
                },
                "a:Estado": {
                    "_text": "Vigente"
                },
                "a:EstatusCancelacion": {},
                "a:ValidacionEFOS": {
                    "_text": "200"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

};
// Todas las propiedades con corchetes, encerradas entre comillas
console.log(data['s:Envelope']['s:Body']['ConsultaResponse']['ConsultaResult']['a:Estado']);
// Las propiedades sin caracteres especiales pueden seleccionarse directamente
console.log(data['s:Envelope']['s:Body'].ConsultaResponse.ConsultaResult['a:Estado']);
```